# My octave code function returns "error: 'num_iters' undefined near line 1 column 37"- Andrew Nguyen coursera machine learning course

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I am currently taking Andrew Nguyen's coursera course on machine learning. For the week 2 assignments, I have to create a function that performs gradient descent. However, everytime i call the function in the command line, it doesn't work and returns "error: 'num_iters' undefined near line 1 column 37". I have attached the code below(which is in a function file).

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
%GRADIENTDESCENT Performs gradient descent to learn theta
%   theta = GRADIENTDESCENT(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters) updates theta by 
%   taking num_iters gradient steps with learning rate alpha

% Initialize some useful values
m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);



for iter = 1:num_iters

    % ====================== YOUR CODE HERE ======================
    % Instructions: Perform a single gradient step on the parameter vector
    %               theta. 
    %
    % Hint: While debugging, it can be useful to print out the values
    %       of the cost function (computeCost) and gradient here.
    %

for iter = 1:num_iters
  h = X * theta;
  theta = theta - (alpha/m)*((h-y)'*X)';
  
    % ============================================================

    % Save the cost J in every iteration    
    J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);

end

end
```

Comment: How do you call the function? Obviously it needs 5 input arguments, if you call it with less, then `num_iters` will not be defined.

Comment: Yes. Without seeing the command with all of your inputs and the exact error message, we're not going to be much help here. The for loop issue mentioned below wouldn't produce the error thou say you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

U have used for loop twice inside the function which is unnecessary.

Try removing one for loop (maybe the one above the "YOUR CODE HERE"